# ffmpeg - executing 2 or more command in one time

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 ffmpeg commands, I execute them respectively, they work, but I want to execute them in one time and one command. How to do that?

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-20:20" -codec:a copy 2.mp4

ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -i picture.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -codec:a copy 3.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i logo.png -i picture.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-20:20[bg];[bg][2:v]overlay=10:10[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See the [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) for a description of the syntax.